# Missing character: There is no semicolon in nullfont

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am aiming at "clean" compilation, that is why I'd like to eliminate this `Missing ; in nullfont`, in the following MWE(s). It all compiles fine, but there are as many as 5 `Missing character: There is no ; in nullfont` warnings, and I know from previous questions that this is usually caused by extraneous ";" in TikZ code. However, I could not see problems in my code.

The first comes `Fig01.tikz`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
%\font\nullfont=cmr10
\newcommand\bulkCoordinates[0]{
        \coordinate (ex) at (10ex,0);
        \coordinate (v1) at (origin);
        \coordinate (v2) at ($(v1)!1!-135:(ex)$);
        \coordinate (v9) at ($(v1)!1!-45:(ex)$);
        \coordinate (v8) at ($0.5*(v2)+0.5*(v9)$);
        \coordinate (v3) at ($(v2)!1!-120:(v8)$);
        \coordinate (v7) at ($(v2)!1!-60:(v8)$);
        \coordinate (v10) at ($(v9)!1!60:(v8)$);
        \coordinate (v11) at ($(v9)!1!120:(v8)$);
        \coordinate (v4) at ($(v3)!0.8!-115:(v7)$);
        \coordinate (v6) at ($(v3)!0.8!-55:(v7)$);
        \coordinate (v5) at ($0.5*(v4)+0.5*(v6)$);
}
\tikzstyle{mystyle}=[
        circle,draw,
        %TODO
        %decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=0.5pt,amplitude=0.1pt},
        font=\small\ttfamily,minimum width=1.2em,inner sep=0pt
]%
\tikzstyle{myedgestyle}=[
    %TODO
    %decorate, decoration={random steps,segment length=0.5pt,amplitude=0.1pt}
]%
\begin{scope}
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \bulkCoordinates
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11} {
        \ifthenelse{\x = 1 \OR \x = 2 \OR \x = 4 \OR \x = 6 \OR \x = 10}
            {\node[mystyle,fill=podo02,text=white] (V\x) at (v\x) {\x}}
            {\node[mystyle] (V\x) at (v\x) {\x}}
            ;
    }
    \foreach \p/\q in {V1/V2,V1/V8,V1/V8,V2/V3,V2/V7,V3/V4,V3/V6,V1/V9,V9/V10,V9/V11} {
        \draw (\p) edge[myedgestyle] (\q);
    }
    \node (picLabel) at ($(V1)!1!35:(V4)$) {(a)};
    \node (metkaT) at ($(V1)!1!-45:(V2)$) {$T$}; %OFFENDING LINE
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=28ex]
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
    \bulkCoordinates
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11} {
        \ifthenelse{\x = 1 \OR \x = 2 \OR \x = 4 \OR \x = 6 \OR \x = 10}
            {\node[mystyle,fill=podo02,text=white] (V\x) at (v\x) {\x}}
            {}
            ;
    }
    \foreach \p/\q in {V1/V2,V2/V4,V2/V6,V1/V10} {
        \draw (\p) edge[myedgestyle] (\q);
    }
    \node (picLabel) at ($(V1)!1!35:(V4)$) {(b)};
    \node (metkaT) at ($(V1)!1!-45:(V2)$) {$T_X$}; %OFFENDING LINE
\end{scope}
```

\end{tikzpicture}

The whole thing is inside the following wrapper:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta,shadings,patterns,tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shadings,shadows,shapes,chains,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,intersections,fit,patterns,fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,intersections,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{podo01}{RGB}{240,228,66} %Yellow
\definecolor{podo02}{RGB}{0,114,178} %Blue
\definecolor{podo03}{RGB}{0,158,115} %Bluish green
\definecolor{podo04}{RGB}{230,159,0} %Orange
\definecolor{podo05}{RGB}{86,180,233} %Sky blue
\definecolor{podo06}{RGB}{0,0,0} %Black
\definecolor{podo07}{RGB}{213,94,0} %Vermillion
\definecolor{podo08}{RGB}{204,121,167} %Reddish purple


\begin{document}
    \input{Fig01.tikz}
\end{document}
```

From reading the logs, I've marked with `OFFENDING LINE` the places that hint to a problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is in the part

```
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11} {
        \ifthenelse{\x = 1 \OR \x = 2 \OR \x = 4 \OR \x = 6 \OR \x = 10}
            {\node[mystyle,fill=podo02,text=white] (V\x) at (v\x) {\x}}
            {}
            ;
```

For the non chosen cases, there is a stray semicolon. Do

```
    \foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,11} {
        \ifthenelse{\x = 1 \OR \x = 2 \OR \x = 4 \OR \x = 6 \OR \x = 10}
            {\node[mystyle,fill=podo02,text=white] (V\x) at (v\x) {\x};}
            {}
```